# geom_smooth() doesn't show while geom_point() works

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I'm trying to plot a geom_smooth line with ggplot2, but it doesn't appear. geom_point works fine, and I don't get any error messages.

```
  participantID token language measurement value
1            CC  Teil   German        F2_0   906
2            DD  Teil   German        F2_0  1638
3            FF  Teil   German        F2_0  1781
4            FH  Teil   German        F2_0  1195
5            GG  Teil   German        F2_0  1796
6            HH  Teil   German        F2_0  1695
```

The 3 variables are: the *measurement* (N= 21: F2_0, F2_5, F2_10, ... , F2_95, F2_100), the *value* for each measurement and *token* (with two levels).

My ggplot line is
`ggplot(mydata,aes(x=measurement, y=value, color=token))+  geom_point()+ geom_smooth()+labs(title="F2 trajectories")`

There are several threads on this issue already, but they don't seem to work for my data set.
Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your `x` variable is categorical.  Given that, what should the relationship look like?  Should the categorical variable be treated as ordinal or numeric or something else?  That may help you figure out if a smooth is a., reasonable and b., doable.  I searched "geom_smooth categorical" and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743776/2461552) may also prove useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest next approach. You are using as x-axis a non numeric value that is why `geom_smooth()` is not working. I would suggest creating a reference value for x-axis and then use facets for `measurement`. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Id variable and plot
df1 %>% group_by(measurement) %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y=value, color=token,group=measurement))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()+labs(title="F2 trajectories")+
  facet_wrap(.~measurement)
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(participantID = c("CC", "DD", "FF", "FH", "GG", 
"HH"), token = c("Teil", "Teil", "Teil", "Teil", "Teil", "Teil"
), language = c("German", "German", "German", "German", "German", 
"German"), measurement = c("F2_0", "F2_0", "F2_0", "F2_0", "F2_0", 
"F2_0"), value = c(906L, 1638L, 1781L, 1195L, 1796L, 1695L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thank you! it  worked by adding group=token in the aes() of the geom_smooth